# MVC, problem with Mapper passing ViewModel to CreateView

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

I need some help. I'm using ASP.NET MVC which I am beginner in.

I'm writing an application with a database and 3 tables (2 tables are just for parent child drop downs, and third is for saving data from dropdowns and fill other forms).

I am using Entity Framework with SQL to connect my database to ASP.NET MVC with autogenerated models from database.

I manually make ViewModel of all three tables and  their fields and I need to pass all data to 1 view (Create View)

Here is my code from Home controller where I am getting error.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(CountryStateContactsViewModel csvm)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(csvm);
    }

    // Error happens here
    Contact contactModel = Mapper.Map<CountryStateContactsViewModel, Contact>(csvm); 
    db.Contacts.Add(contactModel);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

This is the error I get:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Mapper.Map<CountryStateContactsViewModel, Contact>(CountryStateContactsViewModel)

Comment: Can you show your mapper configuration profile?

Comment: Yea, sure but I am not sure exactly what you mean by that :(

Comment: You're using Automapper?

Comment: Yes, yes . How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you made any configuration of the AutoMapper? If so, show it please.

Comment: I didnt, can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use AutoMapper , first you should CreateMap between your classes.

```
public class ContactProfile {
    public AutoMapperProfile() {
        CreateMap<CountryStateContactsViewModel,Contact>();
    }
}

public class AutoMapperConfiguration {
    public static void Initialize() {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg = > {
            cfg.AddProfile(new ContactProfile());
        });
    }
}
```

And finally in your Global.asax:

```
AutoMapperConfiguration.Initialize()
```

Comment: Where I should put those classes ContactProfile and AutoMapperConfiguration

Comment: It depends . For example you can put it in any folder in your startup project.

Comment: So I just make new folder in startup , make class and put both classes in that?

Comment: Yes . It's correct. And don't forget you should introduce AutoMapperConfiguration in your Globa;.asax file.

Comment: I got error Mapper does not contain a definition for initialize at Mapper.Initialize

Comment: It seems that this method is Obsoleted . Try @Kevin Amorim solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to OP comments there is no AutoMapper configuration, and without it AutoMapper cannot resolve mappings.

Define an interface to abstract the mapping methods:

```
public interface IMappingService
{
    TDest Map<TSrc, TDest>(TSrc source) where TDest : class;

    TDest Map<TSrc, TDest>(TSrc source, TDest dest) where TDest : class;
}
```

Implement the interface:

```
public class MappingService : IMappingService
{
    private MapperConfiguration mapperConfiguration;
    private IMapper mapper;

    public MappingService()
    {
        mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            // Define here your mapping profiles... 
            cfg.AddProfile<ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile>();
            cfg.AddProfile<DomainToViewModelMappingProfile>();
        });
        
        // You may not want to assert that your config is valid, and that's ok.
        mapperConfiguration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        mapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
    }

    public TDest Map<TSrc, TDest>(TSrc source) where TDest : class
    {
        return mapper.Map<TSrc, TDest>(source);
    }

    public TDest Map<TSrc, TDest>(TSrc source, TDest dest) where TDest : class
    {
        return mapper.Map(source, dest);
    }
}
```

Now you have to define your profiles (example):

```
public class ViewModelToDomainProfile: Profile
{
    public ViewModelToDomainProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<CountryStateContactsViewModel, Contact>();
    }
}


public class DomainToViewModelProfile: Profile
{
    public DomainToViewModelProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<CountryStateContactsViewModel, Contact>();
    }
}
```

Finally, inject your IMappingService in your controller:

```
private readonly IMappingService _mappingService;

public HomeController(IMappingService mappingService) {
    _mappingService = mappingService;
}
```

And use it like so:

```
_mappingService.Map<CountryStateContactsViewModel, Contact>(viewModel);
```

I like this solution because it encapsulates everything nicely.

EDIT: @Arsalan Valoojerdi was faster than me. But, this way you have two different approaches.

**Note: Do not forget to define your dependency to IMappingService on your IoC container (eg. Ninject).**

Comment: got error at implementing at this rows    cfg.AddProfile<ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile>();
            cfg.AddProfile<DomainToViewModelMappingProfile>();

Comment: @SvenNenadić what's the error? Did you implement both classes ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile and DomainToViewModelMappingProfile?

Comment: The type or namespace name ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile could not be found

Comment: same for DomainToViewModelMappingProfile

Comment: @SvenNenadić implement the classes and import them

Comment: How I should do this help me please

Comment: I've added further explanation to my answer.

Comment: What is this IoC container (eg. Ninject).

Comment: That is already outside of the scope of AutoMapper, you should check it, there is a lot of info online.